# Bulk time entry into timesprite / fogbugz

Tags: fogbugz

Is there a good way to import time data into either timesprite or fogbugz?  Both seem to have very clunky interfaces for adding single items at a time. What I want is a spreadsheet-style format that I can enter a bunch of rows and suck them in.  Noticed timesprite has an import on it, but it seems to only want timesprite formatted XML.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [FogBugz API](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/60/topics/advanced/API.html) to bulk-add time records into FogBugz. I don't know of an existing spreadsheet-entry interface that uses the API to load data into FogBugz, but one could easily be written for the purpose.